# iOS Development. How do I disambiguate personal vs. client team provisioning profiles?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

As a contract iOS developer I have my personal team provisioning profile and I have a team provisioning profile created for my client(s). In Xcode they appear - maddeningly - as identically name profile files with their only difference being their date of creating. Sigh.

Has anyone found a way to disambiguate these multiple team provisioning profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you would have profiles with the same name. Wouldn't you call them something different when you create them?

Either way, in Xcode
- Open Organizer
- At the top, under Library, click Provisioning Profiles
- Right click each one and select Reveal Profile in Finder

This will give you the hexadecimal ID for each profile (they are unique, and change when you make changes to provisioning profiles in development portal)

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to rename the team provisioning profile to something that makes sense on a per-client basis so my head doesn't explode.